# How do I add linked tables to a microsoft access database where the source is stored on Google Drive (for free)?

Tags: database, ms-access, google-drive-shared-drive, linked-tables

So for context, I have a database backend that is stored in Google Drive and I have a frontend with an interface, forms, and reports. The current solution that we have is that all employees in the company have Google Drive for desktop and the source database in the front-end points to the back-end file (as the google drive for desktop app mounts a virtual drive on the computer so it behaves like a local file). The problem comes when we distribute the front-end file to a third party. I would like to be able to distribute the front-end file to a third-party and the linked table source is the back-end file in Google Drive.

I found an ODBC drive for Google Drive online (https://www.cdata.com/drivers/googledrive/odbc/) but this program is quite expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a *link* to the database and a method in the frontend to relink the backend database.

Then the user can:

- download the file
- copy it in a local folder
- relink the backend

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is just one thing. This method would work, but the original database backend in our google drive shared drives wouldn't be up to date when the person to who I distributed the database to makes changes.  Is there a way where I can just add a link as a source file and it would work like that? I tried putting the sharing link as a source db and it didn't work because the link points to a download of the file.

Comment: No. Access requires an SMB file share which Google Drive is not.